# AWS cloudwatch custom metrics data not visible

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created one cron job (cron job runs every one minute) and a shell script to publish HDFS usage to Cloudwatch with the help of [this answer in AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=266893).

My script looks like below:

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# Prerequisites :
# 1. AWS cloudwatch CLI
# 2. JAVA
# 3. AWS credentials file inside AWS cloudwatch CLI directory
#

export JAVA_HOME=$1
export AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME=$2
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=$AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME/credential-file-path.template
export PATH="$PATH:$AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME/bin"

echo '['`date`'] INFO : all paths set.'

CLUSTER_NAME=$3
UNIT="Percent"

#1. Get hdfs report
#2. Grep for all lines containing dfs used data
#3. Grep for percentage data
dfs_used_percent=`hadoop dfsadmin -report | grep -m 1 'DFS Used\%' | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]+\.?[[:digit:]]*'`
echo '['`date`'] INFO : Current hdfs usage percent : ' $dfs_used_percent
echo '['`date`'] INFO : Sending data to AWS cloudwatch.'


mon-put-data --metric-name "HdfsUsed" --namespace "MyCustomMetrics" --value $dfs_used_percent --unit $UNIT
echo '['`date`'] INFO : Result of mon-put-data command : ' $?
echo '['`date`'] INFO : Data sent to AWS cloudwatch. Exiting.'
echo '----------------------------------------------------'
```

I can see that this script is successfully sending custom metric to cloud watch by looking at following logs (echo statements)

```
$ tail -f hdfs-usage-metric.log

[Wed Oct 29 05:23:03 UTC 2014] INFO : Result of mon-put-data command :  0
[Wed Oct 29 05:23:03 UTC 2014] INFO : Data sent to AWS cloudwatch. Exiting.
----------------------------------------------------
[Wed Oct 29 05:24:01 UTC 2014] INFO : all paths set.
[Wed Oct 29 05:24:03 UTC 2014] INFO : Current hdfs usage percent :  14.36
[Wed Oct 29 05:24:03 UTC 2014] INFO : Sending data to AWS cloudwatch.
[Wed Oct 29 05:24:04 UTC 2014] INFO : Result of mon-put-data command :  0
[Wed Oct 29 05:24:04 UTC 2014] INFO : Data sent to AWS cloudwatch. Exiting.
----------------------------------------------------
[Wed Oct 29 05:25:01 UTC 2014] INFO : all paths set.
[Wed Oct 29 05:25:02 UTC 2014] INFO : Current hdfs usage percent :  14.36
[Wed Oct 29 05:25:02 UTC 2014] INFO : Sending data to AWS cloudwatch.
[Wed Oct 29 05:25:03 UTC 2014] INFO : Result of mon-put-data command :  0
[Wed Oct 29 05:25:03 UTC 2014] INFO : Data sent to AWS cloudwatch. Exiting.
----------------------------------------------------
[Wed Oct 29 05:26:01 UTC 2014] INFO : all paths set.
[Wed Oct 29 05:26:02 UTC 2014] INFO : Current hdfs usage percent :  14.36
[Wed Oct 29 05:26:02 UTC 2014] INFO : Sending data to AWS cloudwatch.
[Wed Oct 29 05:26:03 UTC 2014] INFO : Result of mon-put-data command :  0
[Wed Oct 29 05:26:03 UTC 2014] INFO : Data sent to AWS cloudwatch. Exiting.
```

But this metric is not visible in AWS console even after running this script for more than 2 hours.

I cannot see this metric using `$ mon-list-metrics | grep 'Hdfs'` command also.

If I run `mon-get-stats` command on the same machine where cron job is running, I get following output

```
$ mon-get-stats HdfsUsed --namespace AutodeskCustomMetrics --statistics Average
2014-10-29 04:35:00  14.36  Percent
2014-10-29 04:40:00  14.36  Percent
2014-10-29 04:45:00  14.36  Percent
2014-10-29 04:50:00  14.36  Percent
2014-10-29 04:55:00  14.36  Percent
2014-10-29 05:00:00  14.36  Percent
```

but if I run same command from other machine present in same cluster I do not get any result.

Can anyone please help me correctly inserting and getting custom metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. I was posting data with one set of credentials and viewing AWS console with other credentials. :(